# Issue with Java Swing href

Tags: java, html, swing

I have a Href in my XHTML code that reads as follows

```
<a href="https://aaaa.bbbb.cccc.dddd/irj/portal?NavigationTarget=navurl://505cdd9568643d505f993e328f125aaf&tabstrips=8;">Overview of Program <span>Â»</span></a>
```

And its throwing an error as follows.

```
 Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception:
 javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing
 /commons/na_links.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 17] The reference to
 entity "tabstrips" must end with the ';' delimiter.
```

Can someone help me understand what the issue is about

Comment: "its"?  Show us "its".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be because your url is not encoded.

Try with the same url encoded like:

```
<a href="https%3A%2F%2Faaaa.bbbb.cccc.dddd%2Firj%2Fportal%3FNavigationTarget%3Dnavurl%3A%2F%2F505cdd9568643d505f993e328f125aaf%26tabstrips%3D8%3B">test</a>
```

You could do it online using [this](http://www.url-encode-decode.com/) link.

Comment: If the current page-url is say google.com, clicking on this Anchor tag moves to google.com/https%3A%2F%2f........... I rather want to be navigated to https%3A%2F%2f........... Any suggestions?